# How to prove that $4x^3+6x^2+4x+1$ is not a fourth power of an integer, for any $x\in\mathbb N$?

Tags: number-theory, integers

> How do I prove that for all positive integers $x$ it's true that, $4x^3+6x^2+4x+1$ is not a fourth power of an integer?

I've tried doing modulo 3 and 5 checks, and it didn't really go far from there

Comment: Please do not radically change your question like that... If you have another question, [ask a new one](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/ask), do not edit old ones.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If $4x^3+6x^2+4x+1=w^4$, then:
$$ x^4 + w^4 = (x+1)^4 $$
but such an identity contradicts the case $n=4$ of the Fermat's last theorem (there is an elementary proof of that case in terms of Gaussian integers, so the full power of the general FLT is not needed).

Comment: I may be misremembering, but I thought the $n = 4$ case was descent and the $n = 3$ case was Gaussian integers ???

Comment: No the $n=3$ case uses Eisenstein integers.

Comment: wow this is cool. thanks

Comment: @fretty, OK, I was wrong for $n = 3$, but descent is another option (besides Gaussian integers) for $n = 4$.

Comment: I think this is still an overkill, since you have $(x+1)^4$ on the right, not a general fourth power. For example: the polynomial is $(2x+1)(2x^2+2x+1)$; any prime factor of $2x+1$ cannot divide the other factor; hence $2x+1$ is itself a fourth power...

Comment: @CareBear: to prove that $2x+1=u^4,2x^2+2x+1=v^4$ is not possible is not much easier than proving the case $n=4$ of the FLT, I do not think it is an overkill.

Answer (score -1):

Note we can write:
y⁴ = 4x³ + 6x² + 4x + 1
as: 
y⁴ = (x + 1)⁴ - x⁴
and as mentioned is a form of Fermat's Last Theorem.
→ x⁴ + y⁴ = (x + 1)⁴
This instance of FLT was put to rest long before Wiles finally put the problem to rest.  Check out this simple proof:
http://fermatslasttheorem.blogspot.com/2005/05/fermats-last-theorem-n-4.html?m=1

Comment: This is a restatement of the previous answer.

Comment: It is a different form.  The previous answer doesn't explain the difference in consecutive fourth powers.  To the trained eye it is apparently a difference of consecutive fourth powers.  However, the person asking the question apparently doesn't have a trained eye.  All that I did was explain it in a bit more detail.